# pgagent couldn't get a connection to the database

Tags: postgresql, job-scheduling, pgadmin-4, pgagent

I have created a job with steps, but when I click on "Run Now" in pgAdmin, nothing happens. Has anyone encountered and resolved this? Below is a screenshot for some details

[my pgpass.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKtpM.png)

[pgpass.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXhrp.png)

[property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj3qa.png)

when I check the statistics, I have this:

status: failed
output: Couldn't get a connection to the database!

here's my connection string: user=postgres host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydbname password=root

The Postgres Service is definitely running.

(PostgreSQL 15.3, pgadmin4)

I tried the local connection type but it didn't work, I also tried to change the pgpass.conf to mydbname but didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use text instead of images in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I resolved it by not mentioning the password in the connection string and adding a line for my database in the pgpass.conf .